# Initialise Javascript class globally

Tags: javascript, class, es6-class

I have a javascript class in file `class.js`

```
class counter {

  constructor (params) {
    this.counter;
    this.params = params;

  }

  getCounter () {
    return this.counter;
  }

  getParams () {
    return this.params
  }

}
module.exports = counter;
```

I am initializing this class in file `a.js`

```
const counter = require('./class.js');

new counter(params); //Params is an object
```

Now I want to access this in `b.js` using `class.js` (IMPORTANT):

```
const counter = require('./class.js');

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(counter.getParams()) //Returns {}
}, 3000);
```

Due to complexity of application, I cannot use instance from `a.js` and must use `class.js` only.

Is there any way of achieving this? I looked up on internet but I guess I couldn't perform a relevant search.

Comment: export the instantiated object of the class. `const counter = new Counter(); export default counter;`

Comment: @samb102 I won't be able to use constructor method in `a.js`

Comment: FYI, those getter methods are pretty superfluous. You're even violating them yourself by accessing `counter.params` directly…

Comment: @deceze Typo while rewriting code on stackoverflow.

Comment: Well, no, you really should just omit those getters entirely. There's no reason to have them.

Comment: And why can't you use "constructor method in `a.js`"?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need a singleton of an instance of your class ?

Comment: Well, I literally rewrote code while posting it on stackoverflow. Those getters are there for a reason. It's a proper function that accepts additional parameters and perform additional tasks. I can't remove those getters.

Comment: @Seblor Yes! But How?

Comment: This can be done using the ordering of the `js` files imported, if the file creating `object` is loaded before all files accessing the `object`, then the `object` will be available for all `js` files, because it'll be all loaded on `DOM` in that order

Comment: @DevAggarwal The first comment told you how to crate a singleton. What you can also do is export both an instance of your class and your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use of the SINGLETON pattern, which will allow to initialize the class only once and create only one object that will be used by everybody.

---

**Counter.js**

```
// Store the unique object of the class here
let instance = null;

export default class Counter {
  constructor (params) {
    // if an object has already been created return it
    if (instance) return instance;

    // initialize the new object
    this.params = params;

    this.counter = 0;

    // store the new object
    instance = this;

    return instance;
  }

  // return the unique object or create it
  static getInstance() {
    return instance || new Counter();
  }
}
```

---

**a.js**

```
const Counter = require('./class.js');

const counterObj = new Counter(params);
```

---

**b.js**

```
const Counter = require('./class.js');

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(Counter.getInstance().getParams()) //Returns {}
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is there any way to use it without calling `getInstance`?

Comment: There is none that I know of